# What is a good way to access external data from aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I would like to access external data from my aws ec2 instance.

In more detail: I would like to specify inside by user-data the name of a folder containing about 2M of binary data.  When my aws instance starts up, I would like it to download the files in that folder and copy them to a specific location on the local disk. I only need to access the data once, at startup.

I don't want to store the data in S3 because, as I understand it, this would require storing my aws credentials on the instance itself, or passing them as userdata which is also a security risk. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

I am looking for a solution that is both secure and highly reliable.

Answer (score 0):

which operating system do you run ?

you can use an [elastic block storage](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/). it's like a device you can mount at boot (without credentials) and you have permanent storage there.

Comment: EBS doesn't work well for me because (I neglected to mention) that I need multiple instances running at the same time, and you can only connect an EBS volume to one instance at a time.

I've decided to simply pass in a url as user-data and have the instance retrieve the data from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also sync up instances using something like Gluster filesystem. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119873/best-way-to-sync-files-between-two-ebs-volumn) on it.