# Best way to sync files between two EBS volumn

Tags: amazon-ec2

Anyone have better idea for load balancing on EC2. Basically I am using two EC2 window instances with separate EBS volume attached to each instance. I know about how to use load balancer and working fine for me. I have only issue with sharing application data between two instance, my application require large number of photo and PDF upload and I want to make sure replicate in both instance. I don't want to use S3 in this case as we need to pass through REST/SOAP protocol only.

Any idea.

*Update:
I just updated subject line as it was misleading. I want to sync files between two EBS volume attached to different EC2 instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For replication of data across EBS volumes, you can make use of Gluster Filesystem. It will not only provide replication but also high-availability for your data. You can configure gluster across regions also i.e., one instance in US-East and another in US-West. So even one of the region goes down, it will continue serving data to you. The replication happens on the fly.

The Link to configure Gluster Filesystem : [Gluster-Configuration-AWS-Multi-AZ](http://sanketdangi.tumblr.com/post/5601762671/gluster-config-aws-multi-az)

Regards,
Sanket Dangi

Comment: Will it work in Window based system as well? I looked into it but it seems that made for linux base system.

Answer (score 0):

Using S3 will not prevent you from using a REST/SOAP protocol with the client. You just have your application save or get files from S3 instead of the local disk, you don't have to use S3 directly from the client. Transfer & storage to S3 from within EC2 is free in the same region.

Comment: But still it slow down application.

Comment: I have an application that takes uploaded photos from lots of customers and we write directly to S3. In my experience S3 is very fast and has better redundancy than EBS, which had a major outage recently in the US-East region. http://storagemojo.com/2011/04/29/amazons-ebs-outage/

Comment: I will try for that. I am just worried as we need to zip and PDF from those photos and for that I need to get content to my application server. Thanks for suggestion